# Can my answer be undeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderators

I answered the question: [Why does word2vec use 2 representations for each word?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41292858/) with:

> The prof from Stanford's [Natural Language Processing class](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html) gives
>   an answer to that question [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhHOL3TNyJs&t=46m35s).  Basically, two separate word
>   vectors aren't needed but make the optimization go much better.

However, my answer was deleted by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) without any reason given. I think, I gave a a very concise one-sentence summary of how a lecture, linked to in the answer, given on `word2vec` addresses exactly the question. So I believe it's actually very helpful for others who have the same question.

Can my answer be undeleted, please?

Comment: I also see a comment explaining why link-only answers are frowned upon - your answer amounts to exactly that - a link-only answer. In my opinion - it was deleted rightfully and shouldn't be reinstated without you including *an actual answer* - something that stands on its own and answers the question without having to go to the external resource (which is here today but may be gone tomorrow).

Comment: the community can't undelete content deleted by a moderator anyway.

Comment: The answer is pretty meagre - yes you're paying lip service to `it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here` but you still have to follow the link to gather *any* real information. It might make a good undelete candidate when expanded to a *real* summary

Comment: +1, this is a *support* question and users who are actually trying to be good community members deserve some encouragement for actually trying. (Seriously people.)

Comment: @Pekka , the length of an answer doesn't speak to its usefulness - some of the best answers are very short, and some of the worst ones ramble on and on with marginally useful trivia, unneeded speculation, and superfluous verbiage. This one gives a lot of useful information in a small package.

Comment: @Robert `This one gives a lot of useful information in a small package.` nope - it doesn't provide a summary of the external link that would give you *something* to work with were the external link to ever go down. That's the benchmark

Comment: @MartinSmith The last paragraph of the answer specifically describes what to do in the event that a diamond moderator deletes the post.

Comment: Yep fair enough.

Answer (score 25):

I don't consider a link to a YouTube video to be an *answer*. Even if the video is absolutely wonderful, it must be *supplementary* to an answer. Answers must stand on their own.

In such cases, you have two options:

1. Post helpful links as comments, rather than answers.
2. Include—in the body of your answer—a *complete summary* of the necessary information in the video. I should be able to read this summary and thoroughly understand what the answer is and how to solve the problem without needing to watch the video. Otherwise, back to option #1.

Answer (score 7):

First, you should know that link-only answers are taken as low quality because

- links rot rendering the whole answer useless, and
- people ought to not have to jump to *another* site and peruse *their* information to get to answer.

I can't undelete to overrule a moderator's decision. Feel free to post a *new* answer containing the same links *that also* contains enough content to be usable without the link.

Comment: Deleted posts can still be edited, so you don't have to assume good faith. :-) You can wait for actual evidence.

Comment: @CodyGray good point (I also didn't want to check back here later though, so, eh.) I'm pretty sure my recommended course of action is kosher.